# Скрытие и отображение по нажатию на checkbox/radio

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

есть

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="ad[]" value="boards"><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="ad[]" value="sarafan"><br>

<div class="arrow-right">Вперед</div>
```

Надо, чтобы пока не нажат checkbox/radiobutton не было видно div.arrow-right

Comment: Какие-нибудь попыточки предпринимались?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('input').on('click', function(){
 $('.arrow-right').css('display', 'block');
})
```

```css
.arrow-right{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="ad[]" value="boards"><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="ad[]" value="sarafan"><br>
<input type="radio" id="rb1" name="ad[]" value="boards"><br>

<div class="arrow-right">Вперед</div>
```

Comment: А есть ли возможность изменить в этой строке '$('input').on('click', function()' input на класс элемента или id?

Answer (score 2):

```css
.arrow-right {
  display: none;
}

[id^=cb]:checked~.arrow-right {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="ad[]" value="boards"><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="ad[]" value="sarafan"><br>

<div class="arrow-right">Вперед</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  // если нужны оба — &&
  // если хотя бы один — ||
  // сейчас проверка на оба
  if ($('#cb1').prop('checked') === true && $('#cb2').prop('checked') === true) {
    $('#output').fadeIn()
  } else {
    $('#output').fadeOut()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="ad[]" value="boards"><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="ad[]" value="sarafan"><br>

<div class="arrow-right" id="output" style="display: none;">Вперед</div>
```